# Where can I find free or cheap Survey Respondents?

Tags: surveys

I'm aiming to conduct a simple survey, but can't find enough respondents. Do you know where I can find free or cheap respondents for a survey? (Any links for resources please)

Comment: Students ( a potentially biased sample though )

Comment: Thanks, Phillip. I tried SurveySwap and SurveyCircle services, but it's too slow and, I guess, — not representative for my research goal. Maybe you know some resources else?

Comment: Is the user group you want to reach specific? Professional, customers of some product, demographic?

Answer (score 0):

Forums, subreddits, social media.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mechanical Turk: https://www.mturk.com/ - depending on the size of the task, the compensation starts from $0.1. You also have the option to screen region specific candidates. Amazon handles the payments.
2. User Testing: https://www.usertesting.com/
3. Make surveys on SurveyMonkey/ Qualtrics and paste it on social media. If you want specific responses/ targeting a specific group of people you could reach out via email and give the incentive of a gift card.